# Can the concept of interaction-free measurement help us build better detection devices?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-measurements

Interaction-free measurements  are based on the idea that even if interaction is not happening the chance that it may happen may change the result of the experience. such as in the  Elitzur–Vaidman bomb tester, the existence of the bomb can be measured even if there wasn't any interaction with the bomb.

And  also I read that some free interaction measurements structure can get to chance of 99.9% presence of measurements without interaction. which means that if the presence of particle may cause  to an event that is unlikely to happened  such as neutrino interaction or other events we find hard to measure. We may use free interaction measurement to check if such an event can possibly happened which indicate the existence of the particle.

Comment: There is no interaction free measurement. All measurements require the exchange of energy, including the Elitzur-Vaidman bomb tester. There are not even particles. Everything in quantum mechanics is about energy exchange. What you can play off against each other are reversible vs. irreversible energy exchanges. The latter are called "quanta". The former are sometimes identified with "virtual quanta" (but you will get differing opinions on that, depending on how people think about perturbation theory).

Comment: @FlatterMann  yes but my question remains the same is .it possible to use the fact that possible interaction that may happened can change the results of the experience to create extra sensitive sensors ?

Comment: We can never get around "measuring" a full quantum of angular momentum (one Planck unit). We can measure less than a full quantum of energy. In high energy physics we are interacting a GeV electron etc. with matter. On average each interaction removes a few ten to a few hundred of eV of energy from the electron. This is what causes the "particle tracks" in detectors (theoretically explained by Mott in 1929). We can also reduce the localization of a quantum like in EV or with quenched states. I am beginning to wonder if EV is actually a toy model for quenching. That would be funny.

Comment: But i am referring to case that interaction may happened it just not likely to happend such when deceting neutrinos , or  in case of low energy em

Comment: Let me put it this way: if you don't detect a neutrino, then neutrino doesn't detect you either. This follows immediately from energy conservation and the fact that all measurements are irreversible energy exchanges. And the latter follows trivially from the definition of "a measurement has to leave a record" and the third law of thermodynamics.